# How to display a confirm box before submitting a form?

Tags: 7, forms, javascript

On the `node/%/edit` form, when the user clicks the Submit button, I want to show a simple pop-up box with the text "Are you sure you want to save your changes?". When the user clicks `Cancel` (or `No`) then nothing happens. If the user clicks `Ok` (or `Yes`) then the form gets submitted.

I already tried out the A's in the following related Q's:

- [How to display confirm box before submitting an AJAX form in Drupal 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12479118/how-to-display-confirm-box-before-submitting-an-ajax-form-in-drupal-7#12563071) but they already seem to assume the form has been AJAXified. I'm starting from scratch.
- [How to add a confirm dialog to node add and edit forms?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/203329/how-to-add-a-confirm-dialog-to-node-add-and-edit-forms) is too complex since it adds extra validation options based on the user's input.
- [Use a custom JS modal to confirm changes made on node add/edit form before submit](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/204102/use-a-custom-js-modal-to-confirm-changes-made-on-node-add-edit-form-before-submi) seems to be close but like the comments say: it doesn't actually work.

I also read some other A's that used the [Rules module](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) but that is totally overkill.

Comment: Client request? I would find this a bit annoying to see the popup every single time, even when all fields are filled in.

Comment: Client request, exactly :)

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep an eye out on the other Q where you placed a bounty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**confirm_popup.info**

```
name = Confirm Popup
description = Adds a confirm popup when saving all nodes.
package = custom
version = 7.x-1.0
core = 7.x
dependencies[] = jquery_update
dependencies[] = overlay
```

**confirm_popup.module**

```
<?php

/*
 * Implements hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter()
 */
function confirm_popup_form_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  $content_type = $form['#node']->type;
  if ($content_type == 'article') {

    $form['#attached']['js'][] = drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/js/confirm-popup.js';
    $form['#attached']['css'][] = drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/css/confirm-popup.css';

  }

}
```

**js/confirm-popup.js**

```
(function($) {
Drupal.behaviors.confirmPopUp = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {

    $(document).ready(function() {

      $("#edit-submit").attr("type", "fake");    
      $("#edit-submit").attr("id", "fake");

      $(document).on("click", "#fake", function(){
        var box = $("<div class='popup-box'><b>Are you sure you want to save your changes?</b><div class='btns-wrapper'><span class='save-btn'>Save</span><span class='cancel-btn'>Cancel</span></div></div>");

        $("#overlay-content").prepend('<div class="blackbg"></div>').prepend(box);
        $("#overlay-content").addClass('transbg');
        $("#overlay-titlebar").prepend('<div class="blackbg"></div>');
      });

      $(document).on("click", ".save-btn", function(){
        $('#fake').attr("type","submit");         
        $('#fake').attr("id","edit-submit");
        $('#edit-submit')[0].click();
      });

      $(document).on("click", ".cancel-btn", function(){
        $(".blackbg").remove();
        $(".popup-box").remove();
      });

    });

  }
};
})(jQuery);
```

**css/confirm_popup.css**

```
.blackbg { 
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   overflow: hidden;
   z-index: 10;
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.transbg{
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0) !important;
}

.popup-box{
  width: 350px;
  height: 120px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 20;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", Verdana, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}

.btns-wrapper{

   position: absolute;
   bottom: 15px;
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 15px;
   display: block;
   margin: auto;

}

.save-btn, 
.cancel-btn{
  padding: 10px;
  width: 70px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.save-btn{
  background-color: #6bc711;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.cancel-btn{
  background-color: red;
}

#fake{
  width: 34px;
}
```

## Result

[image]

Comment: hi, I'm quite weak at ajax and stuff, how do you operate when you only want it on some node types and wanna display some node value in there?

Comment: @gl_prout I edited **confirm_popup.module** to show you how. If you want to grab a node value, you will need to edit the **confirm-popup.js** file and grab it with with JS. It depends, if it's a text box, you can with `var some_value = $('#field_id').val();` and then you will need to concatenate it inside the text. Ex: `...<b>Are you sure you want to save your changes?' " + some_value + " '</b>...`